# How to fix property missing from an existing type?

Tags: typescript

I am converting an existing Node.js + express application written in plain JS to TS. I understand **why** I get this error, but I do not know the correct way to fix it. The type "Request" comes from @types/express Do I have to extend this type to expect a property inside of body named product? I would to reuse the built-in types from @types/express as much as possible.

```js
app.post('/something', function(req: Request) {
    if (req.body) product = req.body.product
                                     ^^^^^^^^
})
```

**Error from Typescript server**: Property 'product' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream'. (tsserver 2339)

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'as' keyboard like this:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
interface IProduct{
   name: string;
   .
   .
}
app.post('/something', (req: Request) => {
    if (req.body) product = (req.body as { product: IProduct }).product
});
```

If you want to use @types/express you can use generic types:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
interface IProduct{
   name: string;
   .
   .
}
app.post('/something', (req: Request<{}, {}, IProduct>) => {
    if (req.body) { product } = req.body;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to type the request.

but if you can type the request, follow this order:

```
interface P {}; /* params */
interface ResBody {}
interface ReqBody {}
interface ReqQuery {}

app.post('/something', function(req: Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery>) {
    if (req.body) product = req.body.product
                                     
})
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L112

and the error:

> Property 'product' does not exist on type
> 'ReadableStream'.ts(2339)

that's because you need to import the request:

```
import { Request } = from 'express';

app.post('/something', function(req: Request) {
    if (req.body) product = req.body.product
})
```

the global `Request` interface is from the `fetch API`.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you're passing the `body` object from, make sure the object contains a `product` property. If you have a typed `body`, make sure to include the `product` as a parameter.  For example,

```
type ReadableStream = { product: string }
```

Or before you pass `body` to `app.post`,

```
body: { product: "product" }
```